# Enclosing "image path" registry setting of a service in double quotes

Tags: powershell, registry

I want to make this particular registry setting in,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\DSIService
```

existing "Image Path" value :

```
C:\Program Files\HP\HP BTO Software\bin\dsisrv.exe
```

Required "Image Path" value :

```
"C:\Program Files\HP\HP BTO Software\bin\dsisrv.exe"
```

i.e. I just want the path to be enclosed in double quotes, this can be done by manually editing the same, but i was looking for a script which can do the same thing.

I did find powershell commands to get the same done, but somehow it takes every other value except (").
I tried to use (`) to escape quotes but simply doesn't work.

Comment: In powershell you can supply `"` in 2 ways: 1) you can use backtick-doublequote in a string that's already double quoted, or 2) you can use a single quoted string and use the `"` directly. If it's not working **you need to post the code you are using** otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: I have used both of these:      
1] reg add HKLM\system\CurrenControlSet\services\DSIService /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d '"C:\Program Files\HP\HP BTO Software\bin\dsisrv.exe"' /f

         2] reg add HKLM\system\CurrenControlSet\services\DSIService /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "`"C:\Program Files\HP\HP BTO Software\bin\dsisrv.exe`"" /f

But i can't get it done